# How to inject Prometheus metrics bean in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, prometheus

I have certain classes to which I want to inject bean from Prometheus Config as a constructor parameter.

```
@Component
class Foo(
    private val counterMetric: Metric
) {

}

@Component
class Bar(
    private val counterMetric: Metric
) {

}
```

```
@Configuration
class PrometheusConfig {

    @Bean
    fun counterMetric() = Counter.build()
            .name("invite_requests")
            .help("Number of invite requests")
            .labelNames("method")
            .register()
}
```

I can't inject this bean, because Spring Boot has @PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration annotation. How I can deal with it?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'prometheusConfig' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=prometheusConfig; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]] for bean 'prometheusConfig': There is already [Generic bean: class [kz.btsd.messenger.calls.config.PrometheusConfig]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/home/nurbol/BTSDigital/mess-calls/mess-calls-app/build/classes/kotlin/main/kz/btsd/messenger/calls/config/PrometheusConfig.class]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already registered `PrometheusConfig` class, please rename to other name, something like `PrometheusConfiguration`.